# Grails domain classes are not persisted in database

Tags: grails

I have seen a strange issue in grails2.3.7 version. I have around 15 domains classes in my project, all are working fine and persisting into database correctly.

But recently I have added 5 more domain classes , when I restart my server, I can only see the my previous domain classes and 1 recently added domain class name persisted in the database, but the 4 domain classes names are not persisted into database. I deleted the recently created domains classes and added them back again, but I still see the same behavior.

All domain classes are with unique names, not using any reserved words etc for domain classes. It would be if someone helps me to resolve this issue.

The domain 5 domain classes are : All 4 domain classes(Eg1,Eg2,Eg3,Eg4) contains a single Integer variable and belongs to relationship with 5th Domain class(Eg5).  Eg5 hasMany relationship with the Eg1, Eg2,Eg3,Eg4 . I didn't even write any logical code . First I am trying to see whether the domain classes persisting in db.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the domain class field name as "group". I think group is a reserved word in database.

Answer (score 1):

there is nothing on the description that anyone can help with... you need to enable SQL loggin  for a start to see what is going on from a db point of view

So either this :

```
datasource {
...
logSql = true
}
```

or log4j

```
log4j = {
          debug 'org.hibernate.SQL'
          trace 'org.hibernate.type'
}
```

take a look here  http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1604

sorry I have now updated it after reading Burt's funny feedback. Thanks Burt

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have used a reserved "group" word, that is the causing the problem.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: That's SQL logging, not MySQL logging :)  And pick one - either `logSql=true` to dump statements to stdout, or use the Log4j config to log to the console, or a file, or whatever appender(s) you want. But don't enable both as you'll just see 2 of each line.